# Grouping values by custom rules

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Given a table of the following format:

```
Name    | Value
A       | 0
B       | 0
C       | 1
D       | 2
E       | 3
```

How could I query this table in this format:

```
SELECT value,count(*) FROM table GROUP BY value
```

Such that we produced the result:

```
Value   | Count
0.. 1   | 3
2       | 1
3       | 1
```

That is, such that the grouping can have a rule specified that it should group either a range or even a set of distinct values (so we could group anything with `0` or `3` as one row).

(For reference the query above would actually produce the output)

```
Value   | Count
0       | 2
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 1
```

Comment: Instead of value use CASE WHEN value in (0,1) THEN 1 ELSE value END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case construct:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN value IN (0,1) THEN '0..1' ELSE CAST(value AS CHAR(10)) END as values,
  count(*) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN value IN (0,1) THEN '0..1' ELSE CAST(value AS CHAR) END;
```

Comment: This did what I needed; it's quite verbose but as I'm doing it via a PHP script anyway I can just duplicate the case statement in variables in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions comes in to my mind:

First is to use a function for grouping the values

```
SELECT some_function(value) v, count(*) c FROM table GROUP BY some_function(value);
```

The other way is to join the mapping table with group and group relation mappings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the list of values use GROUP CONCAT with GROUP BY(value in ()) with

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value) value, COUNT(value) count FROM table WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY (value IN (0,1)
```

The above wont given you other value counts, but this one will.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value) value, SUM(count) as count FROM (SELECT value, COUNT(value) as count FROM table WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY value) x GROUP BY IF(value IN (1,0),NULL,value)
```